# Path difference on a sphere due to geodesic deviation

Tags: calculus, geometry, spherical-coordinates, geodesy

Between two points of same latitude but different longitudes [spherical coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$] we measure two lengths of arcs  $(s_1,s_2)$ along (1) the geodesic or red great circle (a graphic of numerical integration) and (2) along the constant $ \phi$ non-geodesic thicker purple arc  or latitude.

[image]

There is no difference of these distances at the equator or poles but is a maximum at some intermediate latitude value.

How to find the $\phi$ at which the difference of these arc distances $ (s_2-s_1) $  is a maximum?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: There is a slight issue here as for any given $\Delta \theta$, both $s_1$ and $s_2$ distances change with latitude.  You are asking for the $\phi$ which maximises $s_2-s_1$ fixing $\Delta \theta$ but might get a different answer if aiming to maximise $s_2/s_1$, or if you fixed one of $s_1$ or $s_2$ and then maximised the difference

Answer (score 2):

For convenience of the application we will use earth-like spherical coordinates with $\phi=0$ referring to the equator (so that the poles are at $\phi=\pm\frac\pi2$).
Further we let the azimuthal angle between $s_1$ and $s_2$ be $2\theta\,\, (0<2\theta\le\pi)$.

We seek to maximize over $\phi$ the expression:
$$
D(\theta,\phi)=2\theta\cos\phi-\arccos(\cos^2\phi\cos2\theta+\sin^2\phi)=
2\theta\cos\phi-\arccos(1-A_\theta\cos^2\phi),
$$
with $A_\theta=1-\cos2\theta=2\sin^2\theta$.

Equating the derivative of $D(\theta,\phi)$ over $\phi$ to $0$ we find (besides the trivial case $\sin\phi=0$) the equation
$$
\boxed{\cos^2\phi=\frac{2\theta^2-A_\theta}{\theta^2A_\theta}=\frac1{\sin^2\theta}-\frac1{\theta^2}},
$$
which being resolved gives the maximizing latitude $\phi_\text{max}$.

For small azimuthal separations ($\theta\to0$) $\phi_\text{max}=\arccos\frac1{\sqrt3}\approx 54.74^\circ.$

Comment: I think you could write your answer as $\hat \phi = \pm\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{1-\cos(\theta)}-\dfrac{4}{\theta^2}}\right)$

Comment: @Henry I agree this looks nicer. And probably my choice of $\phi=0$ for the NP rather than for equator may be inconvenient for this application.

Comment: My expression was measured from the equator.  But it may only make a difference to using $\arccos$ vs $\arcsin$ at the end of the calculation

Comment: @Henry I incorporated the form  of the final answer you suggested. Also I have rewritten everything for "equatorial" coordinate system.

Comment: Ok..deleted it....

Answer (score 0):

(Not about my answer, regarding part of discussion with user's answer).

```
F[x_, t_] := t Cos[x] - ArcCos[1 - (1 - Cos[t]) Cos[x]^2]
Plot3D[F[XX, TT], {XX, 0, Pi / 2}, {TT, 0, Pi }, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> " Geodetic_ Devn"]
```

Still I am missing something in the unmodified $\phi$ latitude domain of user's function mentioned above .. ( geodesic deviation is more than half earth radius ! ). Please comment.

[image]

Comment: In the formula you use it is assumed: −π/2<ϕ<π/2. Use these limits and you will see the maxima! For your plot they are too shallow.

Comment: You are evidently measuring $\phi$ from the equator rather than the pole. As soon as $\phi > \frac\pi2,$ you have crossed over the pole. The term $\arccos(1-(1-\cos(\Delta\theta)\cos^2\phi)$ goes to zero at $\phi=\frac\pi2$ and then starts increasing again as $\phi$ increases further, but the term $\Delta \theta \cos \phi$ becomes negative and continues to decrease, so instead of the two terms canceling they reinforce each other. To make the story short, the right-hand side of your graph is nonsensical.

Comment: @user: Thanks, I re-plotted with your $ F(\phi, \theta)$. Please comment.

Comment: The case you're concerned about (more than half Earth radius) is simple to check. Set $\Delta\theta = \pi$ and choose a suitable value for $\phi$, perhaps $\phi = 0.7.$ Now you have a path of $180$ degrees around a line of latitude at latitude $\phi$, whose length is easy to compute; the great circle goes over the pole, and its length is $\pi - 2\phi$ times Earth's radius. Try it. What are the approximate lengths of each path, and what is the difference?

Comment: Let us follow the wise advice of @DavidK and compute the path difference for two points separated by the azimuthal angle $\pi$. For simplicity let us take the latidude $\frac\pi4$. Then the paths along the latitude and over the pole have the lengths $\pi R\cos\frac\pi4$ and $R\frac\pi2$, respectively. Hence the difference is: $$\pi R\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac12\right)\approx0.65R.$$

Comment: @Narasimham Are you satisfied with my comment?

Comment: I appreciate your reply and work, to me looks right. Let us now see a 3D plot...$ (\theta, \phi, s_2-s_1 )$ the max arc difference. Then all the final results are seen in *one plot* convincingly including for small $\theta$,